# Locating elements on pastebin bin selenoum (python)

Tags: html, linux, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I have been trying to do this one thing for a couple of hours now. Basicly I'm doing

```
driver.find_element_by_class_name('paste_code')
```

but I keep getting unable to locate element or something like that. Now the website can be found here https://pastebin.com/ all I need is some ID of the pastebin box where u type stuff. These are the ID's that I would like to get (only need one) Name, ID, Class. Thats bassicly all I need I am very new to python and selenium please no hate. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to type something into textarea, you might use value of `id` attribute:

```
driver.find_element_by_id('paste_code').send_keys("some text")
```

Note that `"paste_code"` is an `id`/`name` value, while `class` name value is `"paste_textarea"`

Comment: i want to paste something so how would i do that?

Comment: and u get this https://pastebin.com/0xHnT9kV when i do driver.find_element_by_id('paste_code').send_keys("some text")

Comment: Cannot reproduce the issue- code works fine from my side... Can you update (edit) your ticket with complete code you use to handle textarea on pastebin.com?